# What is a proper way to introduce a Filter into App Engine app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-platform, servlet-filters

I have an App Engine microservice where all RESTful endpoints are described with Google annotations like `@APIReference @APIMethod`

I need to filter request based on authentication header.

To reduce boilerplate code I want to create something as Filter in Java EE.

Could you clarify how should I do it properly in App Engine?

Maybe I raise this question because I don’t fully understand relationships between Servlets and Google endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the Filter class in your deployment descriptor file. Then you can set your headers inside that filter class. For more reference,
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml#filters

Note : This filter will work for api requests, it will not apply for static resource requests such as requests for .js and .css files.